# Auto Layout in UICollectionReusableView not working on iOS7 but working on iOS8

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicollectionreusableview

I'm working on an app compatible with iOS8 and iOS7.

I have made a collection view header by subclassing `UICollectionReusableView` and the UI has been made with Interface Builder. Here an schema of the header's interface :

`----------------------------
|                           |
|             A             |
|                           |
|---------------------------|
|                           |
|             B             |
|                           |
|---------------------------|
|                           |
|             C             |
|                           |
----------------------------`

### The problem

`A`, `B` and `C` views are link by Leading and Trailing on the super view (`UICollectionReusableView`) and it work fine on iOS8. But on **iOS7** when the view is layout to have the reference size (768pt of width), the subviews have a width of 1216pt (it should be the same width as the superview : 768pt)...

### What I've found

Here are the constraints on the `UICollectionReusableView` :

```
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c4196c0 UIView:A.top == HEADER:0x7be52ff0.top>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c4196f0 HEADER:0x7be52ff0.trailing == UIView:A.trailing>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c419720 UIView:A.leading == HEADER:0x7be52ff0.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c4197b0 HEADER:0x7be52ff0.trailing == UIView:B.trailing>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c419810 UIView:B.top == UIView:A.bottom>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c419840 UIView:B.leading == HEADER:0x7be52ff0.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c419870 UIView:C.top == UIView:B.bottom>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c4198a0 UIView:C.leading == HEADER:0x7be52ff0.leading>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c4198d0 HEADER:0x7be52ff0.trailing == UIView:C.trailing>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7c419900 HEADER:0x7be52ff0.bottom == UIView:C.bottom>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be98df0 HEADER:0x7be52ff0.width == 768>,
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7be98e20 HEADER:0x7be52ff0.height == 512>
```

And here is what happen in the overriding of `layoutSubviews` in my `UICollectionReusableView` by calling `[self recursiveDescription]` in the console :

#### Before calling `[super layoutSubviews]`

```
<HEADER: 0x7be52ff0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 0; 768 512); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7be87300>>
   | <UIView: A; frame = (0 0; 320 360); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7be53190>>
   |    | ...
   | <UIView: B; frame = (0 360; 320 96); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7be6bc50>>
   |    | ...
   | <UIView: C; frame = (0 456; 320 56); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c417360>>
   |    | ...
```

#### After calling `[super layoutSubviews]`

```
<HEADER: 0x7be52ff0; baseClass = UICollectionReusableView; frame = (0 0; 768 512); clipsToBounds = YES; layer = <CALayer: 0x7be87300>>
   | <UIView: A; frame = (0 0; 1216 360); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7be53190>>
   |    | ...
   | <UIView: B; frame = (0 360; 1216 96); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7be6bc50>>
   |    | ...
   | <UIView: C; frame = (0 456; 1216 56); autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x7c417360>>
   |    | ...
```

### Attempts

I've tried to set leading and trailing constants Relative to margin which is not helping.

I've also tried to change manually the frames of `A`, `B` and `C` after the call of `[super layoutSubviews]` and call `setNeedLayout` on these views. But as I expected it crash the app.

### Question

I'm having some hard time to find why this is happening since subviews inside `A`, `B` and `C` views are not trying to expend their superviews.

Is there some debugging techniques that can help me to identify the source of this bug ??

Thank you for your help !

Comment: Have you tried to reset to suggested constraints in IB and see what happens? Editor->Resolve Auto Layout Issues

Comment: I've tried it broke everything on iOS8 & iOS7 and the problem still here on iOS7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some hours I've found by chance the origin of the bug.

My `UICollectionReusableView` was calling `[self layoutIfNeeded]` after everything has been filled with my model object, and I was calling it again in the Controller after data has been set. So I've remove the call that is made inside the `UICollectionReusableView` and it works fine now on iOS7. But I still don't understand why it does that with multiple calls to `layoutIfNeeded`...